# NameError: uninitialized constant Mail::Parsers::ContentTransferEncodingParser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sidekiq

Sometimes when I send mass email on heroku some of them fail with the following error:
`NameError: uninitialized constant Mail::Parsers::ContentTransferEncodingParser`

I have no idea why is that but I think that maybe this maybe caused by using `attachments.inline in mailer`. Any ideas what may cause this problem?

Comment: Did you find out more about this? Just stumbled upon this myself. Retrying the job worked but I don't really like the idea of a Heisenbug here...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I create initializer with following line:

```
Mail.eager_autoload! if Rails.env.production? && defined?(Mail)
```

and that fixes the problem.